# Configuring Routes to Deploy Sub-Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, routes, subdomain, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails `4.0.0.rc2`, Webrick and deploying to Heroku. Let's say I have a main project, "Project A". I've just used the git sub-tree merge strategy to merge in another repo as a sub-project, "Project B".

```
- Project A Root
--- app (Project A)
--- config
--- Project B Root
------ app (Project B)
------ config
------ db 
------ lib
------ etc.
--- db
--- lib
--- etc.
```

How do I configure my `routes.rb` file to map `/blog` (or even a subdomain) for example to the root of "Project B"? I don't readily see a way to tell rails that `/blog` should map to my "Project B" root and not my "Project A" root.

I'd want to be able to access the blog application ("Project B") for example at `blog.projectA.com` or `projectA.com/blog`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can do what you want though with a VPS like Linode / Digital Ocean and using nginx / apache

Comment: If this is not possible (or it is excessively difficult), what is the convention for deploying subprojects? Would it be namespacing them under a blog subdirectory in controllers/ and views/ and models/ ? I don't want to clutter my main projects code and would much rather keep it as a separate project instance

Comment: I'm not sure what the convention is but what I do I just keep it as seperate project instances and then direct nginx to redirect to the correct project according to the URL.